# Distinct values for combination of Keys using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Input data set

```
data.csv
----------
col1,col2,col3
68,emp101,a1
74,emp101,null
56,emp101,a1
67,emp101,a2
45,emp102,b1
78,emp102,b2
23,emp102,b3
```

For the col2, I need to find distinct values for col3 excluding null.

emp101 has 2 distinct values -----> a1,a2
emp102 has 3 distinct values -----> b1,b2,b3

emp101 has 4 records and 2 distinct values, the 4 records must be replicated 2 times with addition of new col4, which will be distinct value of col3 for each copy.

emp102 has 3 records and 3 distinct values, the 3 records must be replicated 3 times with addition of new col4, which will be distinct value of col3 for each copy.

```
Expected Output
col1,col2,col3,col4
68,emp101,a1,a1
74,emp101,null,a1
56,emp101,a1,a1
67,emp101,a2,a1
68,emp101,a1,a2
74,emp101,null,a2
56,emp101,a1,a2
67,emp101,a2,a2
45,emp102,b1,b1
78,emp102,b2,b1
23,emp102,b3,b1
45,emp102,b1,b2
78,emp102,b2,b2
23,emp102,b3,b2
45,emp102,b1,b3
78,emp102,b2,b3
23,emp102,b3,b3


grunt>input1= load 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (age: int, eid: chararray, grade: chararray);
grunt>input2= GROUP input1 by eid;
grunt> input3= distinct input1 by eid,grade;
2017-05-26 08:35:59,056 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 31, column 24>  mismatched input 'by' expecting SEMI_COLON
```

Comment: From Pig Reference: DISTINCT Removes duplicate tuples in a relation. So, DISTINCT does not apply to individual fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the original relation, base.

```
-- Create a relation with col2 and col3
-- Filter out where col3 is null
-- Take distinct tuples (equivalent to records)
col23_rel = DISTINCT (FOREACH (FILTER base BY col3 is not null) generate col2, col3);
dump col23_rel;
(emp101,a1)
(emp101,a2)
(emp102,b1)
(emp102,b2)
(emp102,b3)

-- Now, join col23_rel back to base on col2. This will generate desired output.
jnd = JOIN base by col2, col23_rel by col2; 

dump jnd;
(68,emp101,a1,emp101,a1)
(68,emp101,a1,emp101,a2)
(74,emp101,,emp101,a1)
(74,emp101,,emp101,a2)
(56,emp101,a1,emp101,a1)
(56,emp101,a1,emp101,a2)
(67,emp101,a2,emp101,a1)
(67,emp101,a2,emp101,a2)
(45,emp102,b1,emp102,b1)
(45,emp102,b1,emp102,b2)
(45,emp102,b1,emp102,b3)
(78,emp102,b2,emp102,b1)
(78,emp102,b2,emp102,b2)
(78,emp102,b2,emp102,b3)
(23,emp102,b3,emp102,b1)
(23,emp102,b3,emp102,b2)
(23,emp102,b3,emp102,b3)
```

Comment: It worked.. While filtering null values, if I get blank/null as a value, what is the workaround? do we need to do filter as null.

Comment: Yes. Instead of "is not null" use "is null".